# jQPlot turning on and off series

Tags: jqplot

If I run this code below in jqplot I get all lines(series) rendered on the graph:

```
series:
    [   


        {label:'qqq', color:'#CD0000',show:true},
        {label:'www', color:'#FFAA00',show:true},
        {label:'eee', color:'#9CCB19',show:true},
        {label:'ddd', color:'#3299CC',show:true},
        {label:'ccc', color:'#871F78',show:true},
        {label:'ggg', color:'#BF5FFF',show:true}
    ],
```

but if I run this code below to show only one series on the graph which is fine and the others are crossed out, but if I want to enable them again by unticking them, this does not work anymore:

```
series:
        [   


            {label:'qqq', color:'#CD0000',show:true},
            {label:'www', color:'#FFAA00',show:false},
            {label:'eee', color:'#9CCB19',show:false},
            {label:'ddd', color:'#3299CC',show:false},
            {label:'ccc', color:'#871F78',show:false},
            {label:'ggg', color:'#BF5FFF',show:false}
        ],
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: can you please share the code on how you are trying to turn them on.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it by using this piece of code:

```
graphPlot.series[0].show = true;

graphPlot.redraw(false);
```

You can also specify the index of any series in the above code and then make its show property to true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Add **seriesToggle** under the **legend/rendererOptions** with a value other than 'off'
http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-enhancedLegendRenderer-js.html#seriesToggle

> false to not enable series on/off toggling on the legend. true or a
>   fadein/fadeout speed (number of milliseconds or ‘fast’, ‘normal’,
>   ‘slow’) to enable show/hide of series on click of legend item.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a working example **[here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/blockPlot.html)**

Once you have implemented something and if you still have troubles feel free to ask for any help.